# which file actually write the properties of the project when we load the project into visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have loaded an open source project in two PCs, both Pcs' have same configaration. But when I compare the properties of project in both PCs' are different.

My question is:
which file actually write the properties of the project when we load the project into visual studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of a project's properties are stored in the `.vcxproj` file, except for:

- Properties on the `Debugging` page, which are stored in the `.user` file
- How files are organised in project filters (the tree structure of the project): these are stored in the `.filters` file

Notice that project properties can also reference Property files (`.vsprops`) and incorporate settings from them.

Also bear in mind that property values can contain variable references (such as `$(SolutionDir)`) which are expanded at build time.

Comment: In addition to that, a lot of the properties are variables, and supplied/replaced when visual studio loads the project.